# Not Able to Convert text to required dd-mm-yyyy in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Having a headache trying to resolve below excel problem:
I am using Excel 2003 :
Import thousand of data from text.txt below format & trying to split 
dd-mm-yyyy

-> 6022015  (7 Number)

->26012015  (8 Number)

In Excel, Data Tools>Text to Column>Fixed Width

-> 6!02!2015  (7 Number)

->26!01!2015  (8 Number)

Column Data format, select General, then finish .
For 7 number, succeed in splitting them into 3 columns.
But for 8 number, below error occurs. Below is the results

->26012015  changeto->2 60  12015            " This should be 26 1 2015"

-> 6022015  changeto->6 2   2015

Can someone pinpoint the error and provide a solution please?

Comment: In which format your date values exist "ddmmyyyy" or "mmddyyyy"

Answer (score 0):

Hope your date is in "ddmmyyyy" format then instead of text to column please try find and replace **"!"** with **nothing** then apply the below formula.

```
=IF(LEN(A2)=8,LEFT(A2,2)&"-"&MID(A2,3,2)&"-"&RIGHT(A2,4),"0"&LEFT(A2,1)&"-"&MID(A2,2,2)&"-"&RIGHT(A2,4))
```

Hope this is what you expected :)

Answer (score 0):

Assume the raw data is in either `dmmyyyy` (7 digits) or `ddmmyyyy` (8 digits) format.

1. Simply copy all data into column A (or import the data to column A).
2. Enter into B1 `=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MID(A1,LEN(A1)-5,2),LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-6))`, and copy downwards.
3. Format column B as `dd-mm-yyyy`. Column B will be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
=substitute(a1,"!","/")
```

and for good measure if it's not coming back as a date try adding zero:

```
=substitute(a1,"!","/")+0
```

And/or, if it contains any blanks in the cell (left or right of the text detailed) then trim the cell thus:

```
=trim(substitute(a1,"!","/")+0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use the approach `wilson` took, tearing it apart and putting it back together again. However, if you wish to succeed in the `Text to Columns` wizard, you must either have delimiters or same-length data.

Same-length data is easy to achieve. Just use a "helper column" next to, or, well, anywhere convenient, and use the formula:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=7,")"&A1,A1)
```

copied down however far is needed to get a column of eight character values. Once you have that, then copy the column and `Paste|Values|Special` to get a column of values, not formulas. Use the `Text to Columns` wizard on that, fixed width so you can tell it to interpret things as dates, one single column (you don't want it split up into parts), and tell it `DMY` for the date type.

It will give you one column of output which will now be "real dates" and you can copy that, then paste it over the original data. Or by it, or whatever.

The key is making the data all be eight characters in length so it can all be treated the same:  Excel cannot tell if a seven digit datum is one digit day, two digits month, or vice-versa so you must work with that concern.

If you had some that were six digits, it would be the same basic idea, just a little harder to pad things out.

Also, this works for you BECAUSE you KNOW that the last four digits are year, no two-digit years, and that the months are all two digit values, no one digit months. If you could not be sure of that, it would need a more sophisticated approach.